# Import local typescript react package as a dependency with hot reloading

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, package, create-react-app

I currently have the following problem, I want to use a local react package (`my-react-package`) as a dependency in another react app (`my-react-app`), both are written in typescript.

```
├── my-react-app
│   └── package.json
│   └── src
└── my-react-package
    └── package.json
    └── src
```

I am importing `my-react-package` via `"my-react-package": "file:../my-react-package",` in `my-react-app/package.json` .

When using the `dist` build output of `my-react-package` it works fine, but each time I make a change in I need to build it again, which is very time-consuming for development.

That is why I have tried to use the react code in `my-react-package/src` directly. But when changing  `my-react-package/package.json` from `"main": "dist/index.js"`, to `"main": "src/index.ts"`, importing it leads to the following error in `my-react-app`:

```
./node_modules/my-react-package/src/hooks/state/session.ts 34:31
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (34:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'
| 
> export function useSessionState<_, S>(key: string, initialState: S): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>] {
|   try {
|     const storedState = sessionStorage.getItem(key)
```

I assume this error is related to how webpack handles typescript dependencies. As I am using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/), so I want to avoid messing with the `webpack.config.js` file.

I also want to avoid having `my-react-package` as a folder in `my-react-app/src` as I am planning to import `my-react-package` from multiple other react apps in the future.

Is there a way, `my-react-package` can remain as its own package while I get hot-reloading to work when importing it locally?

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to rebuild every time, you can directly access the files like so:

```
import { thing } from "../my-react-package/src/thing"
```

However, what you probably want is to automatically recompile every time you make a change.

Your question didn't specify whether `my-react-package` uses webpack, so if it doesn't,
you can watch the files being saved and automatically recompile via:

```
tsc -w
```

If you are using just raw webpack for your `my-react-package`, you can edit your `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  watch: true
};
```

This will tell webpack to automatically rebuild.

Alternatively, if you used `create-react-app` for `my-react-package`, you can install `npm-watch`:

`npm i npm-watch`

And then edit your `package.json`:

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-watch": "^0.1.8",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": "src/"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TypeScript will not try to parse or compile anything in your `node_modules`, it will assume all those dependencies are ready to be consumed. In order to be able to consume a TypeScript module you need to explicitly tell TypeScript to compile it. This though will require you to change your `webpack.config.js`. The steps to achieve this are outlined [here](https://openbase.io/js/ts-loader#allowtsinnodemodules).

I would discourage you from taking this road though - I would rather suggest looking into a [monorepo](https://dev.to/t7yang/typescript-yarn-workspace-monorepo-1pao) setup (using `yarn` or `lerna`). In such setup you no longer need to set the dependency as `file:...`, which in turn allows you to:

1. Open a terminal and start a build/watch task in your `my-react-package`
2. Open another terminal and start a build/watch task in your `my-react-app`

Now The changes that you make to your `my-react-package` will be picked up by the watch task in your `my-react-app`

Comment: Your link is dead, do you have an alternative that describes how to consume a TS module?